# Xcode Build Error: Unable to open configuration settings file

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, cocoapods, native

Building a project in XCode throws a strange error

**Full Project Example: **
https://github.com/cristianoalves92/react-native-live-activity/tree/master/example

**Xcode Project: **
https://github.com/cristianoalves92/react-native-live-activity/tree/master/example/ios/LiveActivityExample.xcworkspace

First I ran yarn install in the example root folder

Then I opened ./example/ios/LiveActivityExample.xcworkspace in XCode (Xcode 14.2 on M1 Mac) and got the following error on build attempt:

**Xcode Build Error:**

.../react-native-live-activity/example/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-LiveActivityExample/Pods-LiveActivityExample.debug.xcconfig:1:1 unable to open configuration settings file

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-LiveActivityExample/Pods-LiveActivityExample-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'

**Running arch `-x86_64 pod install` throws this error:**

```
Auto-linking React Native module for target `LiveActivityExample`: react-native-live-activity
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
/Users/roman.staroushnik/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x0000000104ee4000
ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin22]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue also in my React Native app. These lines seem to have fixed my issue:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

(I also restarted XCode. I do not know if it was necessary)